# Choosing a Bathroom Faucets Replacement

Tags: faucet

First off, I just want to start off by saying i'm a total novice when it comes to faucets. We've had the same bathroom faucets in our house for the last 30 years. And most of them are in terrible shape.

After researching for the last couple of days online. A couple of straight forward questions have constantly come across my mind.

- Everything we have in our house is chromed. But I've noticed that chrome faucets are cheaper than Brushed Nickel and Bronze faucets. Why?
- Do Chrome faucets simply get mass produced more than the others? Or are they more likely to deteriorate over time?
- I've also noticed that there are faucets that sell for as little as $65-80 and others sell for $500! Are the materials being used really that different? What exactly determines this drastic range in price?

what types of faucets should I avoid no matter what? And Why?

Comment: When your company's slogan is *buy it for looks buy it for life*, you get to charge $500 a faucet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is probably the most durable & is the cheapest manufacturing process. Brushed nickel has a Satin type of finish rather than chrome's mirror finish & bronze is outright dark. The look you're after is really the only concern for finishes & all will hold up very long to wipe off cleaning no problem.

As far low-quality goes I'd stay away from the cheapest faucets which are usually plastic. Typically, the best way to tell this beyond a box or website description is by the mounting or underside's large threaded tube(s) being plastic. But some plastic faucets have begun to put a brass tube(s) on for the mounting so be wary.

Medium to Highest quality is brass to stainless steel & they're noticeably heavier than the plastic faucets. Medium quality brass is what you've had for 30-years & is quite good & good for water purity. Brass or stainless steel will be the faucet's underside threaded tube(s).

I personally prefer **Single Handle** faucets everywhere as the faucet can be left in the last position for the most comfort & convenience. **Two-handles** (**typically 4-inch spread, measure yours**) are fine but in either case look for **Ceramic Disc valves** to enjoy the best maintenance free longevity. I've had exceedingly good results with the American Standard & Vigo brands for baths & pretty much just Vigo for kitchens.

Finally, you'll need to decide if you want a **Full-Kit** to replace your sink drain & pop-up stopper. A problem you will run into is connecting the new faucet(s) to the plumbing & you'll need a plumber to install his/her recommended faucet(s) or the faucet(s) you've purchased. The new faucets use **"Sold Separately" stainless steel braided flexible lines** where you probably have rigid or hard lines now.

The conversion is best done by finally swapping-out your old **shut-off valves** under the sink (if you have any) for new **Quarter-Turn Ball Valve types** (you don't want anything else & there is nothing better nor comparable) that will allow the new connection lines to install easily.

Happy shopping & try to choose 2 or 3 faucets for the plumber to readily allocate if they obtain them.

Answer (score 1):

Price is *generally* an indicator of quality. I agree with most of @Iggy comments, but one should also consider availability of replacement parts (domestic brands are usually more readily available) and warranty.

I live in the US and bought and installed a high quality domestic kitchen faucet 18 years ago. Over the years I have replaced several parts, all were readily available and sent to me **at no cost** because I hold the manufacturer to their *lifetime guarantee*.